# Empty Adobe PDF fields stripped from document when returned from DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

We use Adobe Acrobat to add fields to a PDF. We want to be able to access these fields and reference their exact location so we can stamp content in their location after getting the PDF back from DocuSign. We do this by manipulating the PDF's bytes using the C# ITextSharp Text PDF library. Unfortunately, opening the PDF in Adobe Acrobat once it's returned reveals that all fields are removed from our document.

Our C# populates most of these fields with text data from our database. 2 fields are left blank, because we want to use C# to superimpose a static image of someone's signature over their location after the document has been signed via DocuSign.

This is okay for what's populated before DocuSign gets our document, because removing the field doesn't visually omit data previously entered into these fields. This is NOT fine when it comes time for us to stamp our static signature image into the document. Our usage of ITextSharp relies on finding a field with a particular Adobe Acrobat ID, getting its location, and "stamping" a static image in that location.

Is there a way to tell DocuSign that we want to maintain all of our PDF fields, their locations, and their IDs?

```
public byte[] StampStaticSignature(byte[] documentBytes)
{
    var signatureContainer = new SignatureContainer();
    var signatureBytes = signatureContainer.GetSignatureBytes();
    var reader = new PdfReader(documentBytes);
    var updatedForm = new byte[] { };
    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream);
    var pdfFormFields = stamper.AcroFields;
    var signatureImage = GetImageFromStream(signatureBytes);

    //_adobeSignatureFields is a list of strings used to 
    //identify the signature fields by their ID set in Adobe Acrobat.
    foreach (var signatureField in _adobeSignatureFields)
    {
        var sigPosition = pdfFormFields.GetFieldPositions(signatureField);
        var page = sigPosition[0];
        var x1 = sigPosition[1];
        var y1 = sigPosition[2];
        var x2 = sigPosition[3];
        var y2 = sigPosition[4];
        var contentBytes = stamper.GetOverContent((int)page);
        var signatureFieldHeight = y2 - y1;
        var signatureFieldWidth = x2 - x1;

        signatureImage.ScaleToFit(signatureFieldWidth, signatureFieldHeight);
        signatureImage.SetAbsolutePosition(x1, y1);
        contentBytes.AddImage(signatureImage);
    }

    stamper.FormFlattening = false;
    stamper.Close();
    reader.Close();
    updatedForm = stream.ToArray();
    stream.Dispose();
    return updatedForm;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your C# code?

Answer (score 0):

Hank, as Inbar mentioned already we will need to examine your code and your API logs to see what could be going wrong. It is very hard to say what went wrong, especially when using 3rd party software like ITextSharp. I'd suggest opening a case with us by visiting our [support center](https://support.docusign.com/contactSupport) and adding a reference to case 09033616

Comment: I added the code we're using to stamp on top of these fields.

Comment: Hank, trying to edit the envelope docs after "the document has been signed via DocuSign" will invalidate the envelope. I think what you need is to use the Stamp tab/field