# The form fields in PDF become empty when it is signed by docusign

Tags: java, pdf

I am trying to fix a bug in which the date field is not populated when the PDF is signed using docusign , but it works fine when it is done via Adobe sign.

When I debug this issue , I see the form fields are not at all coming when the PDF is signed using docusign

```
       PDDocument agreementDocument = PDDocument.load(file);

        PDAcroForm acroForm = agreementDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

        if (acroForm != null) {
            PDTextField printName = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField("date");
            if (printName != null) {
                printName.setReadOnly(true);
                printName.setValue(new SimpleDateFormat(MM_DD_YYYY).format(date));
            }
```

Here I see that the printName is coming as null when the pdf is signed by docusign , but it works fine when it is done by Adobe sign. I have tried with this [Empty Adobe PDF fields stripped from document when returned from DocuSign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71177868/empty-adobe-pdf-fields-stripped-from-document-when-returned-from-docusign)
and this [DocuSign: listing Document Custom fields → Empty JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72529503/docusign-listing-document-custom-fields-%E2%86%92-empty-json-response)

but I seem to be getting lost :( , any help will be greatly appreciated.